# MS Access multiple options for lookup table

Tags: database, ms-access, datatable, ms-office

I'm trying to create a mock POS system database using MS Access 2016.

I currently have a table containing meals - Hamburger, Cheeseburger etc.
I also have an ingredients table - Lettuce, Beef Paddy, Chicken, Cheese etc.

Is it possible to have a lookup field that you can choose what ingredients and the quantity of each ingredient.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use combobox which has a lookup query as its rowsource. You set it to multicolumn and bind the ingredients to the first column and the amount to the second. The source of the data should be a query:

```
SELECT ingredient, amount
FROM yourLookupTable
```

Here are some example setting. Sorry for the german localization!

[image]

Comment: sorry im kind of new. how do i insert a combobox?